# img captions based on src value match

Tags: jquery, drupal, image, drupal-fapi, caption

I am trying t o create img captions based on src value match.

JQUERY : What is the best way to extract "Author-ABC" from an img with src value wwww.abcd.com/images/imagename__Author-ABC__.jpg and replace the alt value with this value.

DRUPAL : Is there a way to preprocess this a drupal template function and save the value in img alt attribute?

Ideas?
Basho

Comment: are the images always going to be imagename_AUTHOR_.jpg, with the author being a variable but the rest of the name static?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your image name always starts with `imagename_` and ends with `_.extension`, you could do something like this:

```
var src = jQuery("#imgId").attr("src");
var imgName = src.replace(/^.*imagename_/,"").replace(/_\.[a-z]+$/, "");
```

Or, assuming that the URL itself will not contain any underscores, you can do this:

```
var src = jQuery("#imgId").attr("src");
var imgName = src.replace(/^[^_]+_/,"").replace(/_\.[a-z]+$/, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing this with JavaScript you could instead hook into Drupal and do all of this when the image is created. I'm guessing you are using a CCK field on a node. With a `hook_form_alter` you can add a submit handler for the form. In it you could do the regex needed to pull out the author name from the img file name and add it as alt attribute.

Doing this you get the markup you want upon creation instead of having to depend on javescript to alter it. This is the flexibility that makes Drupal great and is the *Drupal* way of doing this.